# Vba code to effect a range of worksheets in excel

Tags: vba, excel

How would I go about coding a function to effect a range of worksheets in excel? What I want to do is to check to see if the same worksheet name has been created and if it has I need to end the program, and if it hasn't then I need to copy and paste a template from the Template worksheet to the new sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Ldate As String
Dim Lweekday As Integer
Dim Newweek As String
Dim name As String



Ldate = Date
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Ldate
Lweekday = Weekday(Ldate)

If Lweekday = 4 Then

Newweek = DateAdd("d", 3, Ldate)
name = Month(Newweek) & "-" & Day(Newweek) & "-" & Year(Newweek)
Sheets.Add.name = name
Worksheets("Template").Select
Range("A1:U37").Copy Destination:=Sheets(name).Range("A1")


End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. **Show what have you tried**. What doesn't work. What errors are you getting. What is desired outcome.

Comment: Functions cannot (by design) 'effect' anything except return a value back to the cell they were called from. A macro could, but you will have to provide more specifics than you have offered so far.

Comment: Sorry I have been really busy as of late and hadn't had time to mess around with this. I have updated the post with I copy of the code I am using and a description of more in depth detail as to want I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to affect a name to a range in VBA?

If that's it, here is the base to help you :

```
Dim RgToName as Range
RgToName = "=" & SheetName & "!R" & StartRow & "C" & StartColumn & _
     ":R" & EndRow & "C" & EndColumn
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersToR1C1:=RgToName
```